# How can I use datetimeNormalizer in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, entity, serialization

This is my controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;


public function index($slug, Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer)
  {
    $table = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->findAll();
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer('d.m.Y'), new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
    $data = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json');
    return $this->render('index.html.twig', ['data' => $data]);
  }
```

It is working well, but I get the warning:

> User Deprecated: Passing configuration options directly to the
>   constructor is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use the default context
>   instead.

Comment: Create custom normalizer as a service and tag it with `serializer.normalizer` so that `SerializerPass` can obtain it when the instance is built. Implement the `NormalizerInterface` so you can safely normalize and denormalize however you like and this should to the trick.

Comment: @Artamiel Thank you! This sounds really ellaborate. Is this the only solution? Why is symfony is making it more comlicated in the new version?

Comment: Well, I am not saying that your solution is wrong or inaccurate, but when it comes to Symfony things are a little bit more different, than using a Component independently. The warning you receive is simply trying to tell you to use the full capabilities of Dependency Injection (as you did, with injecting SerializerInterface) instead of creating already existing service manually. So, give it a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is how you build your Serializer, more specifically the DateTimeNormalizer. You can see the [error being triggered in the constructor of that class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/426cf81c16f8d84873fe8ac069c9855841183722/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/DateTimeNormalizer.php#L47) whenever no context is provided.

The easy fix would be to pass in an array as first argument:

```
new Serializer(
    array(
        new DateTimeNormalizer(array('datetime_format' => 'd.m.Y')),
        new GetSetMethodNormalizer()
    ),
    array(
        'json' => new JsonEncoder()
    )
);
```

So just replace `d.m.Y` with `array('datetime_format' => 'd.m.Y')`.

Since you pass in a SerializerInterface anyway, you might want to configure your serializer in your services.yaml instead:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        ... # other default settings
        bind:
            Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface $dateSerializer: '@app.date_serializer'

    Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer: ~
    Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder: ~

    app.date_normalizer:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer
        arguments:
            - { 'datetime_format': 'd.m.Y' }

    app.date_serializer:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer
        arguments:
            - ['@app.date_normalizer', '@Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer']
            - ['@Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder']
```

In your controller you can then just inject your serializer by changing the name of the argument

```
public function index($slug, Request $request, SerializerInterface $dateSerializer)
```

In fact wherever you want to reuse that serializer you can get it by just injecting it with `SerializerInterface $dateSerializer` thanks to the binding in your service configuration.

Side note the bind will only work with Symfony 4.2. In older versions you have to remove the type at the beginning (the SerializerInterface) as this is a new feature. All thew other stuff should work with Symfony 3.4 and 4.0 I think.